# Pyparsing Token Source Range

Tags: python, grammar, pyparsing, rule

How do I extract the source range (begin and end position) of a grammar rule match  programmatically in Pyparsing? I can't use `setParseAction` for this (sub-)rule since I'm inspecting the parse tree contents inside another callback in turn specified as a `ParseAction`. I'm also missing a function to print, in *humane* way similar to `pprint`, the contents returned by `parseString()`. I'm aware of `toList()` but I'm not sure if interesting information, such as context, is stripped away by this member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some sample code showing how to capture a parsed expression's location, and using `dump()` to list out parsed data and named results:

```
from pyparsing import *

# use an Empty to define a null token that just records its
# own location in the input string
locnMarker = Empty().leaveWhitespace().setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: l)

# define a example expression and save the start and end locations
markedInteger = locnMarker + Word(nums)('value') + locnMarker

# assign named results for the start and end values,
# and pop them out of the actual list of tokens
def markStartAndEnd(s,l,t):
    t['start'],t['end'] = t.pop(0),t.pop(-1)
markedInteger.setParseAction(markStartAndEnd)

# find all integers in the source string, and print
# their value, start, and end locations; use dump()
# to show the parsed tokens and any named results
source = "ljsdlj2342 sadlsfj132 sldfj12321 sldkjfsldj 1232"
for integer in markedInteger.searchString(source):
    print integer.dump()
```

Prints:

```
['2342']
- end: 11
- start: 6
- value: 2342
['132']
- end: 22
- start: 18
- value: 132
['12321']
- end: 33
- start: 27
- value: 12321
['1232']
- end: 48
- start: 44
- value: 1232
```

Comment: This feature has been incorporated into pyparsing, as the helper function `locatedExpr`. In this example, `markedInteger` would be replaced with `locatedExpr(Word(nums))`, and it would not require the addition of any parse actions.

Comment: Also take great care if the input text contains <TAB> characters. By default pyparsing calls `string.expandtabs()` on the input string before starting the parse, and this will change the expected locations of strings within the input. To suppress this default behavior, call `expr.parseWithTabs()` before invoking `expr.parseString(inputStringContainingTabs)`.